# Java out of 2 bytes

Tags: java, sockets, byte

I'm doing a project for school using sockets. I already worked with java, but i have never used sockets before, so i'm a little lost.
We are creating a simple race program, that receives the updates of the race, meaning who surpassed, who was surpassed, the lap, the name of the person who is updating and the number of updates made until now.
The problem that i'm having is that we are asked to convert to 1 byte the first 4 variables, but the last (number of updates) we must convert to 2 bytes, and only then will we send to a handler.
I have already converted to 1 byte the four variables, this way (example):

```
byte b = new Integer(lap).byteValue();
out.write(b);
```

This works and it's this way that we should do.
The question may be obvious but i'm having difficulty with it.

Comment: you can use bitwise operations to do that

Comment: Always use `Integer.valueOf` instead of `new Integer`; but since you are effectively just casting with `new Integer(lap).byteValue()`, `(byte) lap` is equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution for two bytes:

```
b[0] = (byte) lap;
b[1] = (byte) (lap >> 8);
```